# We'll work with the primitives used to hold integer values (byte, short, int, and long):

Tags: java

> Given an input integer, you must determine which primitive data types are capable of properly storing that input.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of test cases.
> Each test case, , is comprised of a single line with an integer, , which can be arbitrarily large or small.
>
> Output Format
>
> For each input variable  and appropriate primitive , you must determine if the given primitives are capable of storing it. If yes, then print:
>
> ```
> ! n can be fitted in:
> ! dataType
> ```
>
> If there is more than one appropriate data type, print each one on its own line and order them by size (i.e.:byte<short<int<long).
> If the number cannot be stored in one of the four aforementioned primitives, print the line:
>
> ```
> ! n can't be fitted anywhere.
> ```
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 5
> -150
> 150000
> 1500000000
> 213333333333333333333333333333333333
> -100000000000000
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> -150 can be fitted in:
> * short
> * int
> * long
> 150000 can be fitted in:
> * int
> * long
> 1500000000 can be fitted in:
> * int
> * long
> 213333333333333333333333333333333333 can't be fitted anywhere.
> -100000000000000 can be fitted in:
> * long
> ```

This is the code I wrote.
i also tried Long.MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE , in all these some cases are passed but this codes didnt pass all the cases ,i also tried big integer,But didnt work.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
 

class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        { 
         try{
                long x = sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
                if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");
                if(x>=-32768 && x<=32767)System.out.println("* short");
                if(x>=-(int)Math.pow(2,31)&& x<=(int)Math.pow(2,31))System.out.println("* int");
                if(x>=-(long)Math.pow(2,63)&& x<=(long)Math.pow(2,63))System.out.println("* long");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `(int)Math.pow(2,31)`? Find out the answer, and you will see why your code is not correct.

Comment: You could just read the input as a string and attempt `Integer.parseInt(input);` and if it doesn't explode, print `int`. Same for `Long`, `Short` and `Byte`. Also, what about `Double` and `Float` which are capable of accurately holding integer values up to a certain size (you can do your own research - see [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple problems here.

1. If you read a `long`, how can your 'it does not fit in anything' *ever* trigger? The input is `213333333333333333333333333333333333`, you read it as a long, which instantly fails and throws an exception. Fixing this isn't easy - basically requires a total rewrite. You can't *have* your input as a number (as there's nothing larger than a long). It must be a string, and thus, to check if 'it fits', you can't do `>=-128`, you have to try to parse whatever string you have *into* a byte and see if it works.
2. `Math.pow` is for `double` (i.e., inaccurate) math and doesn't do the job correctly. If you want 'the smallest int', that'd be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, not `Math.pow(2,31)`, which isn't actually what you want. Because complicated - doubles are inaccurate is the oversimplified reason, and `Math.pow` does double math.

Mostly point 2 is irrelevant, because point 1 says this entire approach cannot possibly work in the first place.

This question is somewhat more difficult than a first glance might indicate. Hint: You want `.next()` (not `.nextLong()`), and you want to know how to catch exceptions, and you want to *try* to parse that string using e.g. `Byte.parseByte`, `Long.parseLong`, and so on. If it works, print that data type. If it fails (an exception occurs, which you'd have to catch), don't print it. It'll look nothing like what you wrote so far. Not your fault - this approach is fine until you get to the icky problem that you're supposed to be capable of reading numbers that are so large they don't even fit in a long.

Comment: It’s funny that even experienced developers miss the point that the `Scanner` used to read the number already provides methods for the necessary checks, i.e. `hasNextLong()` to `hasNextByte()`…

Comment: The intent of this answer isn't to say: Here is the full answer, so I didn't want to go that far and spoonfeed.

Comment: I’m not objecting the idea to provide only hints, but the suggestion to call `next()` and parse manually, is pointing into the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3):

Let the JDK do the heavy lifting by having Java's `Number` classes attempt to parse the input:

```
String x = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(x + " can be fitted in:");
if (canFit(x, Byte::parseByte)) System.out.println("* byte");
if (canFit(x, Short::parseShort)) System.out.println("* short");
if (canFit(x, Integer::parseInt)) System.out.println("* int");
if (canFit(x, Long::parseLong)) System.out.println("* long");
if (!canFit(x, Byte::parseByte) &&
    !canFit(x, Short::parseShort) &&
    !canFit(x, Integer::parseInt) &&
    !canFit(x, Long::parseLong)) System.out.println("can't be fitted anywhere.");
```

and define this method:

```
static boolean canFit(String input, Consumer<String> parser) {
    try {
        parser.accept(input);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: bro , can you please explain can fit ,i didnt listen about can fit ever before , i also search on internet but i didnt find any useful ,so can you please explain it to me.

Comment: @Kavishsingh it's a method I added to handle the part of the answer that's common to all primitive types in your problem (see [refactoring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) and [DRY](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). Just copy paste `static boolean canFit ... }` into your Java class (not inside your `main` method, but beside it inside your Solution class).

Comment: Really thanks to you bro.

Comment: Attempting an operation likely to fail, to catch the exception, should only be the last resort, when no pre-check method is available. But here, [it’s rather easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77187687/2711488)

Answer (score 1):

You are making your life unnecessarily hard. You are already using a `Scanner` which can perform all the necessary checks for you. You just have to ask:

```java
int t = sc.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

    boolean fitsByte = sc.hasNextByte(), fitsShort = sc.hasNextShort(),
        fitsInt = sc.hasNextInt(), fitsLong = sc.hasNextLong();

    System.out.print(sc.next());

    if(!fitsLong) System.out.println(" can't be fitted anywhere.");
    else {
        System.out.println(" can be fitted in:");
        if(fitsByte) System.out.println("* byte");
        if(fitsShort) System.out.println("* short");
        if(fitsInt) System.out.println("* int");
        System.out.println("* long");
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind that you have to call `hasNext…()` before `next()`, to query the properties of the next element.

Note, how easy it is to expand to other types:

```java
int t = sc.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

    boolean fitsByte = sc.hasNextByte(), fitsShort = sc.hasNextShort(),
        fitsInt = sc.hasNextInt(), fitsLong = sc.hasNextLong(),
        fitsBig = sc.hasNextBigInteger();

    System.out.print(sc.next());

    if(!fitsBig) System.out.println(" can't be fitted anywhere.");
    else {
        System.out.println(" can be fitted in:");
        if(fitsByte) System.out.println("* byte");
        if(fitsShort) System.out.println("* short");
        if(fitsInt) System.out.println("* int");
        if(fitsLong) System.out.println("* long");
        System.out.println("* BigInteger");
    }
}
```

(An input would not fit into a `BigInteger` if it has a fraction or isn’t a number at all)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
 
class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        { 
           try{
              long x= sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");

                if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");

                if(x>=-32768 && x<=32767)System.out.println("* short");

                if(x>=-Integer.MIN_VALUE&& x<= 
                       Integer.MAX_VALUE)System.out.println("* int");

                if(x>=-Long.MIN_VALUE&& x<= 
                       Long.MAX_VALUE)System.out.println("* long");

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
            }    
        }           
    }
}
```

Thanku all of you for helping me , your answers teaches me a lot of new things.Thanku for all of your favour to me ,now i got the code that satisfies my conditions ,all of you have also given me a code for same output that code is also right but i want to show you my answer,

Answer (score -3):

Use the *[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)* class to evaluate the numbers.

Additionally, utilize a *static data-structure* to provide range values for each *primitive data-type*.

```java
import static java.lang.String.valueOf;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Util {
    static List<Class<?>> fit(BigInteger i) {
        List<Class<?>> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, Range> e : Range.map.entrySet())
            if (e.getValue().withinBounds(i)) l.add(e.getKey());
        return l;
    }

    static class Range {
        static Map<Class<?>, Range> map = new LinkedHashMap<>() {{
            put(byte.class, Range.of(byte.class));
            put(short.class, Range.of(short.class));
            put(char.class, Range.of(char.class));
            put(int.class, Range.of(int.class));
            put(long.class, Range.of(long.class));
        }};
        BigInteger minimum, maximum;

        private Range(BigInteger minimum, BigInteger maximum) {
            this.minimum = minimum;
            this.maximum = maximum;
        }

        boolean withinBounds(BigInteger x) {
            return x.compareTo(minimum) >= 0 && x.compareTo(maximum) <= 0;
        }

        static Range of(Class<?> c) {
            return new Range(min(c), max(c));
        }

        private static BigInteger min(Class<?> c) {
            String s = null;
            if (c == byte.class) s = valueOf(Byte.MIN_VALUE);
            else if (c == short.class) s = valueOf(Short.MIN_VALUE);
            else if (c == char.class) s = valueOf((int) Character.MIN_VALUE);
            else if (c == int.class) s = valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            else if (c == long.class) s = valueOf(Long.MIN_VALUE);
            return s != null ? new BigInteger(s) : null;
        }

        private static BigInteger max(Class<?> c) {
            String s = null;
            if (c == byte.class) s = valueOf(Byte.MAX_VALUE);
            else if (c == short.class) s = valueOf(Short.MAX_VALUE);
            else if (c == char.class) s = valueOf((int) Character.MAX_VALUE);
            else if (c == int.class) s = valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            else if (c == long.class) s = valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            return s != null ? new BigInteger(s) : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example usage.

```java
String s = "5 -150 150000 1500000000 213333333333333333333333333333333333 -100000000000000";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
BigInteger x;
while (sc.hasNextBigInteger())
    System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n%n", x = sc.nextBigInteger(), Util.fit(x));
```

Output

```
5
[byte, short, char, int, long]

-150
[short, int, long]

150000
[int, long]

1500000000
[int, long]

213333333333333333333333333333333333
[]

-100000000000000
[long]
```

Comment: [Don’t use Double Brace Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/2711488)

Comment: @Holger, that is an _anonymous class_.

Comment: Exactly. And you shouldn’t create an anonymous class solely for initializing a `Map`.

Comment: @Holger, here is the _Java_ tutorial for _[anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)_ and for _[instance initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)_.  The _anonymous class_ tutorial even states the following, _"... you can declare the following in anonymous classes: ... Instance initializers ..."_.  I am not too concerned with it's use, considering.

Comment: @Holger, the process you're referring to is called _encapsulation_, and is essentially the abstract for _object-oriented design_.  The _Java_ framework is built using _encapsulation_.

Comment: Your links do nowhere suggest that you should use these features for initializing a collection. The technical reasons why you shouldn’t do this have been given in the link in my first comment. Further, you may search about the design principle to *prefer delegation (or composition) over inheritance*. Your code is a violation of this principle by creating an entirely obsolete inheritance relationship. Can you name an actual reason to create a subclass here, i.e. *not* “because it is possible”?

Comment: @Holger, I'm not too concerned with the using _anonymous classes_.  Try a different question.